Challenging problem about $\upsilon_p$
For positive integers $a,b,c$, $a^b\cdot b^c=c^a$ is given.We must prove that every prime divides $a$,also divides $b$ and solve the equation for $b\geq a$.
I tried to do casework with $b>a>1$ and $a>b>1$ for proving the first statement,I somehow got $a|b$.Saying $b=ak$ can give something,but I can't go further.Same happens for $a>b>1$.

Here is a proof of the first part,
that
$p|a \implies p|b$.
If
$a^b b^c=c^a
$
then, for any prime $p$,
$b v_p(a)+c v_p(b)
=a v_p(c)
$.
If $v_p(a)\ge 1$
then
$a=p^{v_p(a)}d
$
with $v_p(d)=0$
so
$b v_p(a)+c v_p(b)
=a v_p(c)
=p^{v_p(a)}d v_p(c)
$.
If $v_p(b)=0$ then
$b v_p(a)
=p^{v_p(a)}d v_p(c)
$
so
$p^{v_p(a)}|v_p(a)$.
If $p^m|m$ then
$p^m \le m$
or
$p \le m^{1/m}
\le e^{1/e}
\approx 1.4447
$
which is impossible.
Therefore
$v_p(b) \ge 1$.

Please strive not to answer PSQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

I thought that this was an interesting problem that OP had given some effort to.

Please read the linked meta post. PSQ has nothing to do with "interesting". No effort is shown.

@BillDubuque I tried to highlight my effort to what it leads.And I don't get why my post is PSQ

@Bill Dubuque: Would it have been enough if OP had shown the casework rather than just stating that the casework was done?

That's a question for the close voters (and community), which has already been discussed many times in the past on meta.

I am new at the website,would be pleasured to see the previous posts in this topic
